# Google App engine + HTML + PDF

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

I have created a simple website using Google App engine + Python +Jinja2 and MySQL database. The website has one main page (index.html) rendered using Jinja2 from Python code and data is loaded from a MySQL database.

On the index.html page, I have created a horizontal menu (About, Home, Services, Products).

I want to load a new HTML page (say About.html) when I click About. Similarly, when I click Products, (I want to load Products.Html). Here I want to embed a pdf file.

I am not sure how to add these additional HTML pages. Can someone advise.

This is my App.yaml file.

```
application: ckappnotes
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: .*
  script: stn.app

libraries:
- name:  jinja2
  version:  latest
```

I have added these lines to App.yaml.

```
- url: /
  static_files: DTD.html
  upload: DTD.html

- url: /
  static_files: S1.pdf
  upload: S1.pdf
```

Doing so is overriding my original index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` entries need to be unique from each other.  As you noticed, you have overridden your home page with `url: /`.  Instead, you need to create a single `url` for each page like this:

```
- url: /DTD.html
  static_files: DTD.html
  upload: DTD.html

- url: /S1.pdf
  static_files: S1.pdf
  upload: S1.pdf
```

This is fine if you only have a few files, but you may want to use a [Static File Pattern Handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers):

```
- url: /page
  static_dir: page
```

In this example, you put DTD.html and S1.pdf into a new folder named `page`.  Your `index.html` file will reference them as `/page/DTD.html` and `/page/S1.pdf`.  Then, when you want to add a third file, you don't need to change app.yaml, simply add them to the folder and use the same URL pattern.